# I want to automatically delete the data in the browser

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically delete the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109283/automatically-delete-the-data)

I would like to delete my browser data.

If I were to do this manually, the steps would be...
Setting->Application->Application Management>Application information>Delete.

I am using the following.

```
        File file1 = new File("/data/data/android.Create browser/databases/webview.db");
        File file2 = new File("/data/data/android.Create browser/databases/webviewCache.db");

        file1.delete();
        file2.delete();
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2):

Your application can only delete files that exist in its own data directory. It can't do anything to any other data files.  If it could, that would be a security nightmare!

Comment: Why is it that the file which cannot be erased although the file which exists in an original data directory is deleted exists?